# JQuery Modal Dialog Multi Submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am still poor with JQuery.

I have a form with two of input type texts only.
Each input type will open a different Modal Dialog when it's clicked.
Each Modal Dialog has a form with one single input type too.

How to get a value from each Modal Dialog based on parent when it's submitted.

index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Send To CC </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="to_modal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="to" value="John Doe">
        <button type="submit">Submit To</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="cc_modal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="cc" value="Jane Doe">
        <button type="submit">Submit CC</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <form action="all.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="send_to" value="<?php include 'to.php'; ?>" data-target="#to_modal" data-toggle="modal">
    <input type="text" name="send_cc" value="<?php include 'cc.php'; ?>" data-target="#cc_modal" data-toggle="modal">
    <button type="submit">Submit All</button>
  </form>
  
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
  // I don't know how to use this if its required.
  });   
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

to.php

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  $to = $_POST['to'];

 if(isset($to)){
   echo escape($to);
   }
}
?>
```

cc.php

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  $cc = $_POST['cc'];

  if(isset($cc)){
    echo escape($cc);
    }
}
?>
```

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to accomplish? It looks like you just want to send an email or something to multiple people, if so there are much better ways to do so. This seems like an X Y problem, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Give us more information on what you need to end up with rather than what you tried if you could

Comment: I am sorry for the code looks like sending an email form. But it is not. The form is for a re-typing from database to another only.

Comment: Not at all, the code is fine, we just need more info on what it is you're actually trying to do, what purpose does this serve? Knowing that, we can likely get you on track in short order

Comment: The clicked input type should opening a Modal Dialog. When user type some name, the name typed should as a value on parent input type.

Comment: I have tried with one single input type, with above code. But it is not working if I use two input type. The another says undefined index from its value field.

Comment: You're still describing what you have tried. Please explain what your code is supposed to do. If it did work, what would be the result? Without understanding that, it's very difficult to help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
$('#cc_modal').on('submit',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var form=$(e.target);
  $.post(form.attr('action'),form.serialize(),funtion(data){
    alert(data);
//data is value 
//you can use same thing for second form use it value
   });
});
```

and second:-

```
$('#to_modal').on('submit',function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var form=$(e.target);
 $.post(form.attr('action'),form.serialize(),funtion(data){
  alert(data);
  });
});
```